# Is it possible (and appropriate, and how) to use A-Frame animation components to model any kind of physical phenomenon?

Tags: aframe

I am developing a virtual reality physics project, so I will have to be able to model flexibly and accurately many different physical phenomenon. That is why I ask myself if I should create a new component for this purpose or if the built-in A-Frame animate component would be able to do this appropriately.

Specifically, could the animate component model an arbitrary 3D position function? To answer the 'how' part, I think it would be enough for me to know how to model a movement given by the position p(x,y,z) = (ln(t)+t^6,0,0).

Comment: The animation component just interpolates between an initial and end value. If what you want to represent falls in that category, then yes. a-animation is not a simulation tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use animations, you would set the position/rotation/scale of your objects manually according to the simulation and the simulation timestamp.